# Converting a JWT Token to JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jwt

I have a JWT Token which I am trying to convert to JSON - The headers show up fine but not the payload - Any Information will be helpful

My Token

```
eyJ6aXAiOiJERUYiLCJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjNLZmRnLVh3UC03Z1h5eXd0VWZVQUR3QnVtRE9QS01ReC1pRUxMMTFXOXMifQ.3VNNj9owEP0rq9lrSOKwhZJTF3pptapW2m0vFQfjDMSVP5DtBOgq_71jA9tWWrj1Ut8mfvPmvefJC0jvoYY2hK2vi8Jr7kKLXIU2F9w1vsA911uFviBghw4ykDxAzSZsPJlMxiXLyzuWQS-gfoEPwpqAe7r__kq52-3y3Ti3blNUJXtfCIcNmiC58kXPYJlBOGwxdnxDJ9eSrxQuXjE076K222MxisVVnNS6M_InD9Kaq0Bhe9mwWRT1W-ZTt_qBIkR_61Y6UukjTw13eZkz4otf551pFEaMQ287J_A5uYLTxdklCKsUsR2V0AB3IOvE3Cn11SkCnPvrkgDn4g3iR7JD_QQyXOORhGupiA_uDWGcTzM2skcT4_1s21jPc1gOZHCDpqH3rEHzpG8lKYyPPERuNnvHRiUbVSUMQ_amOnZd3ae_I_eBh84n-3GbAsYH67kQ0uDCNolB2EaaTTLiDz6gPu0lvVSrpmmBYtKFl00h-j0RiNQJVTmFYTlksD1FkuSs0aGJ2v5MlEBWiM6lq2j2WeojRZUMl9HW1knajMPTyVtwHWagrDiauUQ-juTKhi-dXqVcH2y4uS3TYRdjrP7LGKvZP4lxejHG8fUYH85Tzz8L3M8XN48td5qLA7EuBzq_AA._juD-OGeaRIRVqIXji_13lHvrpmhw57DpZrZqbNUgjeqjSLwUc8qbzzbai82fGN5KzHgWFKy4v45hzd89GBO7Q
```

I am using jsonwebtoken library

```
var jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

var decoded = jwt.decode(token, {complete: true});
console.log(decoded.header);

console.log(decoded.payload);
```

Output

```
{
  zip: 'DEF',
  alg: 'ES256',
  kid: '3Kfdg-XwP-7gXyywtUfUADwBumDOPKMQx-iELL11W9s'
}
�SM��0�+��kHⰅ�Szi��V�m/�
                        ĕ?���*��c�VZ��R�&~����
a�O36�G��l�X�sXdp�����A�o%)��<Dn6{�F%%�{ٰY�[�S���"D�V:R�#O�\�6�5��=�[�� `�2�<@�&l<�L�%��;�A/�~�š�{���J�����8�nST%{�
                                      C��:v]ݧ�#����'�q������6�A�F�M2�>�>�%�T��i�b҅�M!�=��   U9�a9d�=E��ѡ���L�@V�Υ�h�Y�#E�
                                                                                                                             ����Iڌ���[pf��8��D>��ʆ/�^�\l��-�ac�����?�qz1����S�?
                      ��7�-w���.:�
```

I did same in Python - which works for me perfectly

```
   //Retrieve the Headers which are needed to retrieve the public key
   headers = jose_jws.get_unverified_headers(encoded)
   print(headers)
   

   // Now attempt to decode the JWT/JWS. This would be followed by
   // validation once the public key had been retrieved
   decoded = jose_jws.get_unverified_claims(encoded)

   print(decoded)
```

PYTHON
[image]

JAVASCRIPT

[image]

Comment: Do you have the private key and the other settings that were used to create the token?

Comment: I did the same thing in python - didnt need any keys 

       # Retrieve the Headers which are needed to retrieve the public key
       headers = jose_jws.get_unverified_headers(encoded)
       print(headers)
       #print("")

       # Now attempt to decode the JWT/JWS. This would be followed by
       # validation once the public key had been retrieved
       decoded = jose_jws.get_unverified_claims(encoded)

       print(decoded)

Comment: https://jwt.io/ gives me the error message _"invalid signature"_ The payload is not valid. It looks like the token is broken or incomplete.

Comment: works perfectly with python - just javascript - I am messing somewhere

Comment: It doesn't work with https://jwt.io/

Comment: Yeah - I saw that - but it works with my python code

Comment: You posted an invalid token and a probably correct code. Not much I could do to help here.

Comment: @jabaa that token is valid - it works with python code but not javascript - thats why jwt.io also fails - i tried all resources - now I am stuck here - so I am here for help

Comment: You're saying that https://jwt.io/ is broken and you're the first one that found the problem after many years?

Comment: let me add you screenshots - there is no winning over you :)

Comment: I don't need your screenshot. I believe you that the token works in your code. But that's not a prove that the token is valid. It only means that you somehow handle an invalid token.

Comment: I suggest using the jose package instead of jsonwebtoken. It appears more capable: https://github.com/panva/jose

Comment: Note that the payload does need to be a valid JSON object. If that screenshot is showing the actual payload... that's why jwt.io wasn't working; it's not a valid payload. Apparently whatever Python tool you're using isn't validating the JWT's payload.

Comment: Now that makes sense

Comment: Look at the third comment: _"
jwt.io gives me the error message "invalid signature" The payload is not valid."_

Comment: @jabaa as long as you don't have the public key you can't verify the signature on jwt.io

Comment: @jps Try it yourself. The error message contains more details. It exactly described the problem. It's able to see that the payload is not an object and gives the RFC specification.

Comment: yes, it says that the payload is not a valid json, which is obvious, but that has nothing to do with the signature

Comment: @jps I copied a part of the error message. I wasn't able to copy and paste the whole message. The token isn't valid because the payload isn't valid. That's all I've said from the beginning.

Comment: Yeah thats true - But what I am trying to do is get that payload to display to the console in a readable format like how python does - I dont care about the validity - thanks for the help @everyone - Even jwt.io prints it with those funny characters - i just wwant to print it like how python does

Comment: [RFC 7519](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519) describes the format of a valid token. Your token isn't valid JWT. The format isn't specified. It depends on the implementation how it handles your token. You have to find an implementation that does the same that your Python code does or you have to implement this JWT dialect yourself.

Comment: Thanks @jabaa - That really helps

Comment: What is the real goal here? In the title you write "to JSON" and then later that Python works fine, but what Python prints is also not JSON. The payload is not JSON, maybe when you unzip it in some way (the header suggest som kind of zip format), but I also don't see the Python code unzippin anything

Comment: The python does give json after decompress with zlib - but this is what I am trying to do https://c19.cards/

Comment: _But what I am trying to do is get that payload to display to the console in a readable format like how python does - I dont care about the validity_: You could display the data hex encoded:

Comment: `var base64url = require('base64url'); var payload = "3VNN...q_AA"; var payloadDec = base64url.toBuffer(payload).toString('hex'); console.log(payloadDec);` with `base64url` from https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64url.

Comment: The equivalence to the result of the Python code is proved if you hex encode the result of the Python code, e.g. `print(decoded.hex())`. There is probably also a NodeJS function on the web that outputs hex encoded data in Python style, but the pure hex encoding is the more common format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zip: 'DEF'` indicates the payload is deflated. You may try [inflating](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_zlib_inflateraw_buffer_options_callback) it back.

That being said, "zip" or compression is only defined for JWE (JSON Web Encryption), not JWS (JSON Web Signatures) or JWT. A proper JWT payload MUST always be a top level JSON object and be without compression.